# Creating a Custom ISO

Tags: package-management, iso, custom-distributions

I've got the OK at work to drop some Windows machines and install Ubuntu on them. I will be installing Precise on them, as it is an LTS. What I would like to do is create an ISO with certain packages removed, and others installed by default (to save me having to do the same steps on each machine).

What is considered the current best way to do this. I Vaguely remember using remastersys, but that was a couple of years ago, so am assuming that things may have changed since then! Most of the resources I can find online are from 2009/2010.

Advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Checkout in-depth  solution http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd.  Also possible duplicate .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [remastersys](http://www.remastersys.com/ubuntu.html) to create a custom ISO.

Comment: Not anymore: http://www.remastersys.com/. Seems to have been forked by OS/4 though: http://system-imaging.blogspot.no/2013/04/remastersys-304-2-for-ubuntu-posted.html